# Ionic2 - Refused to display 'https://m.facebook.com/mypagedomain' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: iframe, ionic2

I am using an iFrame in my ionic 2 app to show my facebook page.
But I get this error:
Refused to display 'https://m.facebook.com/mypagedomain' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

The reason I am using iFrame not inappbrowser plugin because I want to show my app header all the time. In inappbrowser I am not able to show header.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Themeable Browser plugin. It's like the InAppBrowser but it allows styling so that it can match the theme of your app.

Ionic Native link: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/themeable-browser/

Github repo: https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

Comment: I tried this plugin already but it is also not providing full customisation. Changing font size of toolbar title is not possible. Also back button is different in size than ionic navbar back button.